# What is the correct way to pass information from my program to the calling script (on exit)

Tags: linux, shell, exit

I wonder, what is the proper way to pass information from my program to the calling script when it exits? Suppose I have "Program X" and a shell script that should do the following:

> 1) Call "Program X" that can return with "State A" or "State B"
>
> 2) After sucessful execution of "Program X", continue with 3A) or
>   3B), depending on its return status
>
> 3A) Do some things which cannot easily be done in "Program X"
>
> 3B) Do some other things which cannot easily be done in "Program X"

Of course I could simply use the return code to indicate how the shell script should continue. However, I think it is a widely accepted convention that an exit code of 0 indicates success, and all other values indicate errors. From this point of view using the exit code to determine the subsequent control flow (after successful execution) would clearly be an abuse of the system.

So my question is: What is the correct way to do achive this?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: When you call a program, it will return the exit status, '0' no-error, or a positive error code on failure, by convention. (not all programs conform, but all normal ones do) In your script, you simply test for successful execution of the program, e.g. `if ! ./program; then #handle error; fi`. That's pretty much it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I literally stated that I do not want to use the exit code system and my reasons for this as well that 3A) and 3B) have nothing to do with successful execution.

Comment: You cannot do it without using the exit code. (unless you do something really screwy like look at something `Program` did, or pipe its output to a `read` and test that). You asked **"What is the correct way to do achive[sic] this?"** -- the answer is to check the exit code.

Comment: Do you have three possible outcomes ("A", "B" and fail)?  If so, you'll need process substitution (`case "$(programX)" in "StateA") do3A;; "StateB") do3B;; esac`).  But it's easier if you can use the exit status (like with `grep` or `test`) - that's what it's for!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of command substitution in shell.

**Command Substitution**

Suppose that `ProgramX`, `3A` & `3B` are your executables.

Instead of returning `State A/State B` simply echo `3A/3B` based on condition
in `ProgramX` Then simply use command substitution

```
$(ProgramX)
```

Above will run `3A` or `3B` accordingly.

<sup>**Note:** The downside is that you won't be able to print anything else to `stdout`.</sup>

---

**Edit : Why not append 3A or 3B to the end of ProgramX based on condition**

ProgramX

```
#at the end
[ 'condition for 3A' ] && 3A 
[ 'condition for 3B' ] && 3B
```

You're not breaking any convention here by the way

---

**Edit : The exit status way**

If you'd like to do it the exit status way, then in `ProgramX` based on condition return  58 or 59. Well you could practically return anything but 58 is the decimal # corresponding to 3A in hex and 59 for 3B.

ProgramX

```
#at the end
[ 'condition for 3A' ] && exit 58
[ 'condition for 3B' ] && exit 59
```

Then do

```
[ $? -eq 58 ] && 3A
[ $? -eq 59 ] && 3B
```

Comment: That is I nice idea in principle. It however means that I cannot write any other information to `stdout` which is certainly not ideal.